# Allow multiple instances of an SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a "Space Invaders" game in swift, when the user touches the screen a bullet is shot from the ship, but when I try to touch it again while the bullet is moving across the screen I have an NSException and the game breaks. How do I set up the action so that there can be multiple instances of the action, so that the shooter is semi automatic. Below is my current scene controller.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    let heroShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heroShip")
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    heroShip.position =  CGPointMake(self.size.width/6.0, self.size.height/2.0)
    self.heroShip.zPosition = 1.0
    self.addChild(background)
    self.addChild(heroShip)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    bullet.position = CGPointMake(heroShip.position.x + bullet.size.width/2, heroShip.position.y)
    let action = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width + self.bullet.size.width, duration: 0.5)
    self.addChild(bullet)
    bullet.runAction(action, completion: {
        self.bullet.removeAllActions()
        self.bullet.removeFromParent()
    })
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Comment: If you touch the screen while the bullet is moving, you need to create another bullet right?

Comment: so you want to have multiple bullets shot from one ship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have multiple bullets shot from one ship, you have to create multiple instances of a bullet. What you have now is `bullet` property of `GameScene` class which is a mistake.
You probably want to instantiate bullets dynamically in your `IBAction`

So try something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(heroShip.position.x + bullet.size.width/2, heroShip.position.y)
    let action = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width + bullet.size.width, duration: 0.5)
    self.addChild(bullet)
    bullet.runAction(action, completion: {
        bullet.removeAllActions()
        bullet.removeFromParent()
    })
}
```

and remove

```
let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
```

from the top of the class

Comment: Yes thats correct, I realized that after I posted this, there was never a new bullet node. Thanks for your help anyway!